# Unzip archive with single file and rename output to match archive name

Tags: bash, command-line, rename, zip

The goal is to unzip many zip files and rename the resulting file to the original archive name.

Given a folder with many zip files, most of them containing a file called `bla.txt`, but of course there are some exceptions. All is known is that every file has a single file, which is a txt file.

```
./zips/
    a.zip - contains bla.txt
    b.zip - contains bla.txt
    c.zip - contains somethingelse.txt
    d.zip - contains bla.txt
    ...   - ...
```

output should be

```
./zips/
    a.txt
    b.txt
    c.txt
    d.txt
    ...
```

Current best shot, which extracts everything but leaves me with a ton of folders:

```
for z in *.zip; do unzip $z -d $(echo 'dir_'$z); done
```

maybe something like

```
for z in *.zip; do unzip $z; mv 'content_name.txt' $z; done
```

But how is the content name obtained?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could continue with the `-d` idea, and simply rename any extracted file to the desired "zip name minus the zip plus txt":

```
mkdir tmp
for f in *.zip; do unzip "$f" -d tmp && mv tmp/* "${f%.zip}.txt"; done
rmdir tmp
```

Alternatively, you could pipe the output from unzip into the appropriately-named file:

```
for f in *.zip; do unzip -p "$f" > "${f%.zip}.txt"; done
```

Comment: The pipe has a (beneficial) side-effect. In case there are more files present (table files in my case) they are appended. This is exactly the behaviour i would want in the exceptional (forbidden even) case of multiple files in a single zip.

Answer (score 3):

The command `unzip` has its own option `unzip -Z1 zipfile.zip` to show the actual compressed filename within zipped file which is taking `zipinfo's` option `-1` as it's `zipinfo -1 zipfile.zip`. so you could simply do as below and there is no need to create a temp directory and `mv` will done in place in current directory.

```
for z in *.zip; do 
    unzip "$z";
    mv "$(unzip -Z1 $z)" "${z%%.*}.txt";
done
```