# Linux zip command query

Tags: zip

I am taking a dump of database as below:

```
pg_dump -c -p 5432 <DB_NAME>| zip --encrypt Name.zip -
```

I don't want to use minus '-' sign for stdin; instead I want to use a filename with date for daily backups.

I tried few things but to no avail.

Comment: Is  my answer below satisfactory? If so, please consider accepting it with the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're piping data to `zip`, *all it has* is stdin. If you want a filename for zip, then you'll have to create & use one:

```
filename=$(date +%Y%m%d.dump)
pg_dump -c -p 5432 <DB_NAME> -f "$filename" &&
  zip --encrypt Name.zip "$filename" &&
rm "$filename"
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff it works however, the only reason i wanted to avoid minus "-" is when i unzip the file it unzip the files as minus sign.

Comment: If that's the only reason, then consider unzipping the file using `-p` ala [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/382416/117549)

Comment: If (from your answer/edit) you're looking to automate the password entry, consider the `--password` option to zip, along with it's warnings.